# After loading it shows current activity and then shows next activity

Tags: android

In my activity am using loader.After loading success it shows the current activity and then moves to next activity.After success i dont want to show the current activity.I just simply need to move to next activity.How can i rectify that?Please help me.

Am using the following code:

```
 public static void showLoadingWindow(Context context){
        if(mLoadingWindow !=null)
            return;

        mLoadingWindow = new Dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar);
        mLoadingWindow.setContentView(R.layout.window_loading);
        try {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.circle1_ani);
            //AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.circle1_ani);
            ImageView circle1 = (ImageView) mLoadingWindow.findViewById(R.id.loadingWindow_pic1);
            circle1.startAnimation(animation);

            Animation animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.circle2_ani);
            //AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.circle1_ani);
            ImageView circle2 = (ImageView) mLoadingWindow.findViewById(R.id.loadingWindow_pic2);
            circle2.startAnimation(animation2);

            Animation animation3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.circle3_ani);
            //AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.circle1_ani);
            ImageView circle3 = (ImageView) mLoadingWindow.findViewById(R.id.loadingWindow_pic3);
            circle3.startAnimation(animation3);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

        mLoadingWindow.show();

    }
```

Comment: me also getting same problem,every time after getting success showing the same activity after 3 seconds it is going to next activity.if you find solution tell me.

Comment: Where ever u are dismissing the loader than try to navigate the activity to another activity...

Comment: if i got response as success i am hiding that window and then redirecting to another activity.then why it is showing current page again ?

Comment: if u have any example for avoiding this tell me